# Deploying to Heroku, Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy my rails app to heroku. The app is uploaded but does not run properly for some reason. When I type

> heroku run rake db:migrate

I get an error saying

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)

I am using puma for the server and I will post some of the files that might cause the problem... Please ask for anything that might cause this error!

config/database.ymi

```
  production:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: FastOrder_production
  pool:     5
  username: <%= ENV['FASTORDER_DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['FASTORDER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  template: template0
  url:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
  pool: ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS']
```

config/puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: did you add procfile under project folder? as stated https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server

Comment: Under the procfile they say "However we recommend generating a config file" which I have posted

Comment: That's different. you have config/puma.rb but you dont have `Procfile file` a file containing this line `web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

Comment: Thanks but I get the same error after creating a procfile :/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
production:

pool: <%= ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
```

Now you can set the connection pool size by setting a config variable on Heroku. For instance if you wanted to set it to 10 you could run:

```
$ heroku config:set DB_POOL=10
```

This doesn’t mean that each dyno will now have 10 open connections, but only that if a new connection is needed it will be created until a maximum of 10 have been used per Rails process.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your db first:

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

Also, check this Heroku doc about DB connections: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Comment: This caused the same error "could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)". Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "host"=>"ec2-52-273-201-84.compute-1.amazonaws.com", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"dej0vekqovntg", "pool"=>"ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS']", "username"=>"fluwgnxblabla", "password"=>"blablabla", "template"=>"template0", "port"=>5432}